# About same name interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

As we know, if we write some same interface in TypeScript, they will be merged.
Just like

```
interface Point {
    x: number
}

interface Point {
    y: number
}
```

we got

```
interface Point {
    x: number
    y: number
}
```

If we write some function in interface.

```
interface Point {
    (x: number): number
}

interface Point {
    (x: string): string
}
```

How can i write a object to let it meet "Point" interface.
I have tried the following methods

```
interface IPoint {
    (x: number): number
}

interface IPoint {
    (x: string): string
}

let f: IPoint = function (x: number | string): number | string {
    if (typeof x === "number") return 114514
    else if (typeof x === "string") return "114514"
}
```

my teacher told me it will be compiled "Overloading of functions", so i writed this code, but it is wrong.
I need help, thanks....

Comment: This question seems to be asking "how can I implement an overloaded function type".  The parts about declaration merging seem to be background information that isn't really relevant to the problem you're having.

Comment: Please see the answers to the other questions for more information.  [This](https://tsplay.dev/Nrnp1N) is one way you could proceed; overload function statements are checked more loosely than overload function expressions.